# PHP - Is it safe to use $_SERVER in CLI to get execution start time?

Tags: php

I do not wish to rely on a `time()` call made to a start of the script. Instead, i find `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` more favourable. I tried that on CLI and it works.

Since I read docs which say information in the `$_SERVER` array is not guaranteed, and the array being named as `$_SERVER`, i was wondering if it safe to use `$_SERVER` on the CLI. The doc for `$_SERVER` on php.net says it is "Server and execution environment information". Will `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` always be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible (although rare) for `REQUEST_TIME` to not be set, as can be seen [here](https://3v4l.org/TWQXY).

I'd recommend falling back to `time()` if it's not set. eg.

```
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

if(!$time) {
    $time = time();
}
```